# MigraDoc - tables from a datasource

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am using Migradoc and can so far only see that tables are generated with values being added one cell at a time. I was hoping there was a way of applying some kind of datasource that automatically populates the cells and adds the required number of rows automatically.

I have been searching but not found anything pointing towards this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the MigraDoc [source](https://github.com/empira/MigraDoc/blob/master/MigraDoc/src/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel/DocumentObjectModel.Tables/Table.cs) - it seems that this is not possible and Table is just a simple wrapper class with no special DataSource binding possibilities

Comment: Thanks for looking into it a bit more... I will just manually run it in then. Appreciate you taking the time for this.